# Price optimization using Python

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

Imagine working on the rental prices of homes in a major Indian city before and after Covid19, with prices being significantly higher post-covid. Suppose as a property broker, I need to offer a very close friend of mine a *rate card with high discounts so that my offered prices match the pre-covid rates*. This phenomenon is called **Price Neutrality** in our line of work.
My Initial Rate Card that I offer to my general customers looks like this:

Table 1

| Area in sq. feet | Area Range in sq. feet | Price in INR 1k |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 510 | 501-650 | 22 |
| 560 | 501-650 | 23 |
| 610 | 501-650 | 24 |
| 660 | 651-800 | 25 |
| 710 | 651-800 | 26 |
| 760 | 651-800 | 27 |
| 810 | 801-950 | 28 |
| 860 | 801-950 | 29 |
| 910 | 801-950 | 30 |
| 960 | >950 | 31 |
| 1010 | >950 | 32 |

Now in our line of work, assume that the discounts are always provided in the following manner:

Table 2

| Area Range in sq. feet | Discount% |
| --- | --- |
| 501-650 | 0 |
| 651-800 | 0 |
| 801-950 | 0 |
| >950 | 0 |

This means that *any discount percentage I apply to these pre-defined Area Ranges gets applied to all granular area values in that range*.
Now that very close friend of mine has already shortlisted the following properties:

Table 3

| House No. | Area in sq. feet | Area Range in sq. feet | Pre-covid price | Post-covid price | Required discount% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 560 | 501-650 | 3 | 23 | 86.96% |
| 2 | 710 | 651-800 | 6 | 26 | 76.92% |
| 3 | 1010 | >950 | 5 | 30 | 83.33% |

Now to match my offered prices with pre-covid rates, I have calculated the required discount percentages in the last column above.

So my Discount Chart looks like this now:

Table 4

| Area Range in sq. feet | Discount% |
| --- | --- |
| 501-650 | 86.96% |
| 651-800 | 76.92% |
| 801-950 | 0 |
| >950 | 83.33% |

Also, my refreshed Rate Card has now become the following:

Table 5

| Area in sq. feet | Area Range in sq. feet | Initial Price in INR 1k | Discount% | Discounted Initial Price in INR 1k | Final Price in INR 1k |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 510 | 501-650 | 22 | 86.96% | 2.87 | 2.87 |
| 560 | 501-650 | 23 | 86.96% | 3.00 | 3.00 |
| 610 | 501-650 | 24 | 86.96% | 3.13 | 3.13 |
| 660 | 651-800 | 25 | 76.92% | 5.77 | 5.17 |
| 710 | 651-800 | 26 | 76.92% | 6.00 | 5.17 |
| 760 | 651-800 | 27 | 76.92% | 6.23 | 5.17 |
| 810 | 801-950 | 28 | 0.00% | 28.00 | 5.17 |
| 860 | 801-950 | 29 | 0.00% | 29.00 | 5.17 |
| 910 | 801-950 | 30 | 0.00% | 30.00 | 5.17 |
| 960 | >950 | 31 | 83.33% | 5.17 | 5.17 |
| 1010 | >950 | 32 | 83.33% | 5.33 | 5.33 |

Please note that if I simply apply the calculated discounts on my initial post-covid prices, there is a price disparity for the following Area values: 810, 860, 910.

To handle this, I am starting from the bottom of the column and if I find a smaller property with rate higher than the current one, I will copy up the rate of the current one for that smaller property. Hence, the flat rate of 5.17 has been copied up until an equal or cheaper property has been found (this copy up logic stops when I encounter the property with area 610) to ensure the *business constraint that a smaller property should not be more expensive than a bigger property.*

Also, my friend's shortlisted property data looks like this now:

Table 6

| House No. | Area in sq. feet | Area Range in sq. feet | Pre-covid price | Post-covid price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 560 | 501-650 | 3 | 3.00 |
| 2 | 710 | 651-800 | 6 | 5.17 |
| 3 | 1010 | >950 | 5 | 5.33 |

Now if I take a pivot of the above data, it would look like this:

Table 7

| Row Labels | Sum of Pre-covid price | Sum of Post-covid price | Diff | Price Neutrality |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 501-650 | 3 | 3 | 0.00 | 0.00% |
| 651-800 | 6 | 5.17 | -0.83 | -13.89% |
| >950 | 5 | 5.33 | 0.33 | 6.67% |
| Grand Total | 14 | 13.5 | -0.5 | -3.57% |

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

I need your help with optimizing the above problem so that the Grand Total in the above pivot table is within [-1,1]% and also the row level Price Neutralities are as close as possible to 0%. All kinds of coding approach, be it some pre-existing python optimization package or some code from scratch, are appreciated.

Thanks in advance and apologies for the long question.

I have written the following code (it is able to compute till Table 7 above) and I'm not sure how to proceed further to solve the above problem statement:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Table 1
rate_card = pd.read_clipboard()

#Table 2
discount_matrix = pd.read_clipboard()

# function to implement the copy-up logic on a single column

def transform(col): # passing each column of a dataframe as a list
    
    result = [] #list to store the resulting column with copy-up rule applied
    
    # going to check for business constraint violation from the bottom up
    for i, val in enumerate(list(col)[::-1]): # hence reversing the list of column values
        
        if np.isnan(val)==False: # handling non-null value situations
            
            if i == 0: # the last non-null value in the column will remain intact
                result.append(val)
                
            elif np.isnan(result[-1])==True: # handling the situation where the comparison is between a null and a non-null value in the column
                result.append(val)
                
            elif (val <= result[-1]) and (np.isnan(result[-1])==False): # keeping the current value intact if business logic is maintained
                result.append(val)
                
            else: # the copy-up logic implementation in action
                result.append(result[-1])
        else: # handling null value situations
            result.append(val)
  
    return (pd.Series(result[::-1])) # reversing the list again to restore to its original order

# Table 3 without the last column
data = pd.read_clipboard()

# Calculating the discounts
post = 'Postcovid price'
pre = 'Precovid price'
discount_df = data.groupby(['Area Range in sq. feet']).agg({post:'sum',pre:'sum'}).reset_index()
discount_df['required_discount'] = ((discount_df[post] - discount_df[pre])/discount_df[post]).replace(np.inf, 0)

# Entire Table 3
data_with_discount = pd.merge(data, discount_df[['Area Range in sq. feet','required_discount']], how='left', on=['Area Range in sq. feet'])

# Table 4: Mapping the calculated discounts to the corresponding Area Ranges
discount_matrix2 = pd.merge(discount_matrix,data_with_discount[['Area Range in sq. feet','required_discount']],how='left',on=['Area Range in sq. feet'])
discount_matrix2.drop(['Discount%'],axis=1,inplace=True)
discount_matrix2.fillna(0,inplace=True)

# Table 5: Implementing the business constraint that a smaller property should not be more expensive than a bigger property
rate_card2 = pd.merge(rate_card,discount_matrix2,how='left',on='Area Range in sq. feet')
rate_card2['Discounted Initial Price in INR 1k'] = rate_card2['Price in INR 1k']*(1-rate_card2['required_discount'])
rate_card2['Final Price in INR 1k'] = transform(rate_card2['Discounted Initial Price in INR 1k'])

# Table 6
final_data = pd.merge(data_with_discount,rate_card2[['Area in sq. feet','Final Price in INR 1k']],how='left',on='Area in sq. feet')

# Table 7: The pivot
post = 'Final Price in INR 1k'
pivot2 = final_data.groupby(['Area Range in sq. feet']).agg({post:'sum',pre:'sum'}).reset_index()
pivot2['Diff'] = pivot2[post] - pivot2[pre]
pivot2['Price_Neutrality%'] = round(pivot2['Diff']*100/pivot2[pre],2)

# The overall price neutrality
overall_pn = round(sum(pivot2['Diff'])*100/sum(pivot2[pre]),2)
print(overall_pn)
```